# Doctrine returns proxy object when joining table with nullable relations

Tags: php, symfony, join, proxy, doctrine

I am trying to retrieve entities from one class joined with another class. 
Not all entities actually have joined entities.

It's kinda like the following statement:

```
SELECT a, b FROM A a LEFT JOIN B b ON a.id = b.aid GROUP BY a.id;
```

or in code:

```
$query_builder = $em->getRepository('repository_of_A')->createQueryBuilder('a');
$query_builder = $query_builder->leftJoin('a.b', b);
$query_builder = $query_builder->groupBy('a.id');
$query = $query_builder->select('a, b')->getQuery();
$entities = $query->getResult();
```

Now the problem is that whenever there is no entity B for A, Doctrine returns a proxy object for A.
Because I work with reflections I need the real object instead of the proxy.

In the attached screenshot the object with index 26 has no corresponding entity B for A (Shop).

[image: Shop Entity (A) is a Proxy]

Does anyone know why and how can I solve this problem?

*Note: I know that I could just use the classname instead of the entity when using reflections, but I would also like to understand the problem here as it may affect the runtime...*

*Edit: Attached a screenshot*

Comment: Seems strange.  Does a have any more associations on it?  In any event, when using Doctrine 2 you need to be able to handle proxies.

Comment: Actually there are a lot more associations, but the query only asks for A and B.
Well, I use `ClassUtils::getClass(...)` now to ensure that the reflections will still work. However, I am still interested in solving this..

Comment: The other associations will cause proxies to be created to support lazy loading.  The only work around that I know of would be for you to do some sort of data conversion or make your own Doctrine 2 hydrator.  But your best bet to to just have your reflection code support proxies.

Comment: Well thx first, but I still don't get it.. The other associations may be proxy objects, but why is my main entity a proxy object? I don't care about the other associations because I only need the primitive data of A (and the primitive data of the joined entity B). Therefore proxies for all other related entities are just fine. As I said, my code works even with proxies using the ClassUtils of Doctrine.

Comment: This A and B stuff is confusing.  Is A your main entity?  If A has associations (i.e. array collections) then A will come back as proxy.  There are ways to setup your query so you only get the exact properties you need.  But that usually means you can't update and persist changes back to your database.

Comment: Well A is the Shop and B are for example Comments. So when I want to retrieve shops and I left join their comments, I get the Shop as a proxy object when there is no comment for this shop. But as shown in the screenshot above, all shops with comments are returned as entity.

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is that fields are not loaded, then before using reflection check if Doctrine loaded the entity and load it otherwise:

```
if (
    $object instanceof \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Proxy
    && !$object->__isInitialized()
) {
    $object->__load();
}
// ... your code
```

But as I see from your screenshot, you have misidentified the issue. If you select `a` first (as in your example), then there will be no proxies in the result list.

As I would guess, in your example all Shop entities are in some association (not selected via query, but for example from `$country->getShops();`) and `Shop [70]` is not a proxy only because somewhere before that point Doctrine has already loaded it. If entity is in map (by ID) - it's used instead of proxy as it's already loaded.

Comment: Actually I use a DQL Statement to get all Shops joined with their comments similar to the one described above. The screenshot shows my result set given by that query. That's why I don't understand the proxy object.